# getarchives_where hook not giving me the correct links in my archives

Tags: wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

I am using the getarchives_where hook to filter and display only archives for a custom post type.

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where' , 'getarchives_where_filter' );

    function getarchives_where_filter( $where , $r ) {  
      $post_type = 'blog-posts';
      return str_replace( "post_type = 'post'" , "post_type = '$post_type'" , $where );
    }
```

It mostly works - It displays 'November 2011' (I only have one custom post for November) but the link to November 2011 is still linked to the archives for general posts.

Instead of example.com/blog-posts/2011/11 it sends me to example.com/2011/11

How can I fix this?

I should mention that I 're-saved' my permalinks and that didn't help the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to re-save my permalinks and update the .htaccess file with the code Wordpress gave me.